# Can I use the contents of the OfficeJS bootstrap token

Tags: jwt, single-sign-on, office-js

In my Word Addin I obtain a bootstrap token with the command:

```
const bootstrapToken = await OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken();
```

I send this token to the backend to verify if the user has the right to our service. For that purpose I need some information about the user.
When I inspect the token on the jwt.io website I can see that the information I need is present in the token.

My question: Can I decode the token and extract the necessary information or do I need to use the bootstrap token to call MSGraph and get my information from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the information you need is in the bootstrap token, then you can just extract it and use it.